# Scrolling to an element and clicking on it

Tags: r, firefox, rselenium

I am trying to web scrape the data from the Flipkart site. The link for the webpage is as follows:
https://www.flipkart.com/mi-a1-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmexnsrtzhbbneg?aid=overall&pid=MOBEX9WXUSZVYHET

I need to automate navigation to the NEXT page by clicking on NEXT button the webpage. Below is the code I'm using

```
nextButton <-remDr$findElement(value ='//div[@class="_2kUstJ"]')$clickElement()
```

Error

```
Selenium message:Element is not clickable at point
```

I even tried scrolling the webpage as suggested by many stackoverflow questions using the below code

```
remDr$executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", nextButton)
```

But this code is also giving error as

```
 Error in checkError(res) : Undefined error in httr call. httr output: No method for S4 class:webElement
```

Kindly suggest the solution. I'm using `firefox browser` and `selenium` to automate using `R` programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind using Chrome driver, the following code worked:

```
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c('--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1880,1000',  "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage")
))

remDr <- rsDriver(port = 4565L,browser = "chrome",extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remCl <- remDr[["client"]]

remCl$navigate("https://www.flipkart.com/mi-a1-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmexnsrtzhbbneg?aid=overall&pid=MOBEX9WXUSZVYHET")

remCl$findElement(using = "css selector", "._3fVaIS > span:nth-child(1)")$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

We shall first scroll to the end of the page and then click **Next**.

```
#Navigate to webpage
remDr$navigate("https://www.flipkart.com/mi-a1-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmexnsrtzhbbneg?aid=overall&pid=MOBEX9WXUSZVYHET")
#Scroll to the end
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "html")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key="end"))
#click on Next
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '//*[@id="container"]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[13]/div/div/nav/a[11]/span')$clickElement()
```